# Delay in Golang Consumer Receiving Kafka Messages After Connecting to Kafka

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

*I'm new to Golang and Kafa so this might seem like a silly question.*

After my Kafka consumer first connects to the Kafka server, why is there a delay (~ 20 secs) between establishing connection to the Kafka server, and receiving the first message?

It prints a message right before `consumer.Messages()` and print another message for each message received. The ~20 sec delay is between the first `fmt.Println` and second `fmt.Println`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
    cluster "github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster"
)

func main() {

    // Create the consumer and listen for new messages
    consumer := createConsumer()

    // Create a signal channel to know when we are done
    done := make(chan bool)

    // Start processing messages
    go func() { 
        fmt.Println("Start consuming Kafka messages")
        for msg := range consumer.Messages() {
            s := string(msg.Value[:])
            fmt.Println("Msg: ", s)
        }
    }()

    <-done

}

func createConsumer() *cluster.Consumer {
    // Define our configuration to the cluster
    config := cluster.NewConfig()
    config.Consumer.Return.Errors = false
    config.Group.Return.Notifications = false
    config.Consumer.Offsets.Initial = sarama.OffsetOldest

    // Create the consumer
    brokers := []string{"127.0.0.1:9092"}
    topics := []string{"orders"}
    consumer, err := cluster.NewConsumer(brokers, "my-consumer-group", topics, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to connect consumer to Kafka")
    }
    go handleErrors(consumer)
    go handleNotifications(consumer)
    return consumer
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1"
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

broker-1:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.0.1"
    hostname: broker-1
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_BROKER_RACK: rack-a
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092'
    KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
    KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
    KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
    KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: 'broker-1'
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker-1:9092
    CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
    CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
    CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "orders:1:1"
```

Comment: How many messages are in your topic? Kafka may take a while to seek to the beginning if there's a lot of data to go through.

Comment: @Peter Under 100 messages in that topic. There are a total of 2 topics, with the second topic having under 10 messages. Kafka and Zookeeper are running in Docker containers on a 2018 i7 Macbook Pro with 16 GB of memory

Comment: @Peter Performed `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` to clear all the Kafka messages, and the delay is still just under 20 seconds.

Comment: I have used similar configuration with yours in my application. And from what I have seen, whenever I started my application and try to connect to Kafka, it will needs some time for the GroupCoordinator of Kafka to rebalance/re-stabilize the group consumer. In my case, that's the reason of the delay and it's the way Kafka works...I think there is nothing wrong with the code. Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

After my Kafka consumer first connects to the Kafka server, why is there a delay (~ 20 secs) between establishing connection to the Kafka server, and receiving the first message?

> There can not be that much delay because consumer used message channel
>   which receive messages from kafka. As soon as the message is available
>   in kafka queue it will be sent to message channel which consumer can
>   receive.

Coming to you code implementation :-

```
for msg := range consumer.Messages() {
    s := string(msg.Value[:])
    fmt.Println("Msg: ", s)
}
```

`consumer.Messages()` returns a channel and `for` loops over the channel which returns a message whenever it is available inside channel.

Refer to this question [How to create a kafka consumer group in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56679704/5821354) to connect using sarama. you don't need sarama-cluster for connection.